# Why my PhoneGap app is starting slowly on android device?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

I've been working with PhoneGap for about two weeks now, yesterday I've build a new android app all went well except that the app starts very slow on my android device. It first shows me for three seconds just a black background except the navbar. So I want to ask how to boost it up or which files I could remove or what I've done wrong please I would be happy if you explain me also the file structure. Thanks in forward for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is little bit vague. Please, give us more information about your app, about your config and what you’ve already tried.

If my app is slow on any device, I do generally the following:

1. Check if the same problem occurs in the browser
2. What’s going on at the start of the app in the browser (Chrome Dev Tools)
3. If nothing unusual happens, check the logs on the device

For Android, I’m using Logcat for checking what’s happening on the phone.

In order to use Logcat:

1.) Enable debugging mode on your Android phone

2.) You need Android Studio

3.) Connect your phone to your computer and start Logcat in Android Studio 3.1.2
[image]

4.) Check the logs while you are starting your app on the phone 
[image]